# I want to open a url with a specific app, I got the HTML link for the intent but no idea how to convert it to java

Tags: java, android, android-intent

As the titles states I want to open a url with a specific app (a dutch version of ebay). I found a link on the website (openend in chrome browser) which does just that.

This is the link:
//intent://advertisements/m967511191#Intent;scheme=marktplaats;package=nl.marktplaats.android;end

So I'm wondering if some knows how to implement this in my app.

Thanks!

Comment: is it a java app? Android? What do you mean by "open"? Lauch a browser with the URL? Read the contents within your program?

Comment: Yes it's  a Android java app. What I want is for my application to open/start this "dutch ebay app" on my phone and direct it to the link which my application provides. This link points to an item on the "ebay site".

When I open the item/link in the chrome browser, there is a html link in the header which open the "ebay-like app" and displays the item. I copied the link in the question.

So what I want is the implemnt this in my app, so that my app open the "ebay-like app" and displays the item.

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear: you want your Android app to launch another android app?

Comment: Yes, let's take ebay as example. Let say my android application has the following link:http://www.ebay.com/itm/50-Android-Hacks-/271589256634?hash=item3f3bfb2dba (it's just an ebay item). I want my application to open this item with the ebay app. Instead of ebay it's a different app but the idea is the same. Sorry if I'm not explaining well English isn't my first language.